# Describe the orbit structure of the action of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ on the space of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, orbifolds

I am reposting this question for better responses after deleting the previous one. I am studying orbit structures in linear algebra  and I am having a bit of trouble visualizing the orbit structure of positive definite symmetric matrix $b$ when the group $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is acting on the space of symmetric bilinear forms (I know there is a one to one correspondence between symmetric bilinear forms and symmetric matrices so I am going to work with the latter).
If the action defined is $S$ -> $A$$S$$A^T$ where $A$∈ $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ what will be the orbit $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.$b$ as a set( $b$ is the positive definite symmetric matrix)? Will it turn out to be the space of symmetric matrices ?

Comment: It's brave to state that you are literally creating a duplicate of a previous question. That's a path to a speedy closure for being a duplicate.

Comment: To answer your question, all that is preserved is the sign of the eigenvalues of your matrix (which are real, since the matrix is real symmetric). So you can map your matrix to be diagonal with entries $+1$, $-1$ and $0$. This is called the signature of the form. Now Wikipedia to the rescue.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I had deleted my previous post before posting this one. So there won't be any problems i guess.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven from what you are saying " all that is preserved is the sign of eigenvalues"  so the symmetric structure isn't necessarily preserved right?

Comment: Well, if $B$ is symmetric then $ABA^T$ is symmetric, as $(ABA^T)^T=ABA^T$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Well $B$ isn't only symmetric but  positive definite symmetric matrix.  I get your point but One question thou, if $A$ is any invertible matrix , $A$$B$$A^T$ doesn't really need to be positive definite, right? And the set of all products of this form  will  be exactly the space of symmetric matrices?

Comment: I answered this earlier. The signature is the number of eigenvalues that are positive, negative and zero. Two symmetric matrices define the same form wrt a change of basis if and only if they have the same signature. Positive-definite symmetric matrices have all eigenvalues positive, so all are related by $B\mapsto ABA^T$.

Comment: @David A. Craven I am still a beginner in this course so  Let me make sure i got this right, I need to define the notion of signature to find the orbit structure ? as You said that two symmetric matrices define the same form iff they have the same signature. So  $B$ being positive definite matrix has the signature (n,0,0) which is the same as the signature of $A$$B$$A^T$ , using $B$= $P$$D$$P^T$ where $P$ is an invertible matrix,  $D$ is diagonal matrix with positive entries , right ? But is there a way i can show that $A$$B$$A^T$ is positive definite without using the notion of signature?